# Phing symlink on remote server

Tags: jenkins, deployment, phing

I am struggling with a test deployment and I need to make a remote symlink.

What I have tried:

`<symlink target="${ftp.destination.dir}" link="/public_html/test2"/>`

It gave me an `IOException` and I realized it tried to create it **locally**.

A quick hack solution I am testing is to create a php file which makes the symlink that will be called within the current job:

```
<http-request url="http://mySecretJobLink/symlink.php" verbose="true" method="POST">
    <postparameter name="target" value="${ftp.destination.dir}" />
    <postparameter name="link" value="/public_html/test_symlink" />
</http-request>
```

My question: Is there a way to create a symlink on a remote server but without a SSH account (FTP/SFTP upload)?

P.S: In conclusion I can't use **SSHTask** `<ssh username="john" password="smith"
host="webserver" command="ls" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FTP protocol does not support symlinks, only "real" files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, found out the hard hay :D